# how to get transaction information from paypal account

Tags: c#, .net, api, paypal

Work on C# Desktop project,I have an account on paypal ,From my desktop application want to get my paypal account  transaction information.
Need help to get transaction information from paypal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into the paypal API?
https://www.x.com/developers/paypal

If so, you might want to look into the "TransactionSearch" or "GetTransactionDetails" operations.

https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/transactionsearch-api-operation-soap
BTW, they have have a Name Value Pair option in case you're like me and despise SOAP :)

Comment: both links above are dead